# Data required for Dual Dirac PDF

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, dirac-delta

I have a simple question regarding the dual Dirac PDF. If I have a set of deterministic data, e.g.,

d = [-2ps, 2ps, -2ps, 2ps, -2ps, 2ps]

Would the resulting PDF look like a dual Dirac PDF? Where there are two impulses at -2ps and 2ps?

This makes sense (to me) because if I were to plot the histogram (with 1ps bins) it would just be 3 counts for -2ps and 2ps.

Am I correct or way off? Thanks.

Comment: What sort of process is generating these data?  Does it really make sense to characterize it as a discrete distribution embedded in a continuous domain?

Comment: Background: I am studying jitter which is a discrete-time process. I assumed I have a clock with the above deterministic jitter.

Comment: Yes, but what set of values does the jitter admit?  What sort of background clock is this analysis relative to?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean. I have assumed the clock generator has deterministic absolute jitter of -2ps and 2ps.

Comment: Yes, but what is the clock resolution?